# break long-no-spaces-lines on commas, dots, hyphens or other special chars

Tags: css

I'm trying to display various texts on small screens (phones)
text is justified but it happens that there is a line with long word /formula / string, that won't fit

There is the possible ***word-break: break-all;***, but it breaks lines too arbitrary, I would need a in-between solution like shows the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsa5t/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insert the `<wbr>` tag to specify an allowed direct line breaking opportunity.

The theoretically more correct method is to insert the zero-width space character, U+200B (`&#x200b;`), but it fails badly on some old browsers.

A treatise on preventing and allowing line breaks in HTML:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

Comment: It does its job when used to specify line breaking opportunities: http://jsfiddle.net/TXWtH/

There is no end tag, and the tag is to be placed at each point where you wish to allow a line break.

Answer (score 2):

not sure what your asking but you can use

`word-wrap:break-word`

Comment: yes it's better even if 'broken' is broken like this br+oken http://jsfiddle.net/Jsa5t/2/

Comment: you can try `word-spacing:1px` or `letter-spacing:`

Answer (score 1):

If you can new line
when have an dot(.) text try this code on your css file:

```
.your_class{
white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```