# CSS Break Word on Commas

Tags: html, css

I am trying to break a word based on commas instead of spaces

I have seen the solutions that include adding the `<wbr>` tag to your HTML, however, for dynamic information now I need another script to insert it into the HTML text and if the user doesn't have JS enabled it doesn't really do me much good.

As of now, I am using a combination of:

```
white-space: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

It works as an OK solution, however, both of these solutions I found (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/1887101; [break long-no-spaces-lines on commas, dots, hyphens or other special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373459/break-long-no-spaces-lines-on-commas-dots-hyphens-or-other-special-chars)) are more than 3 years old - so I am wondering if there are any more recent solutions available for this issue?

Sample string:

> C31C636363-Thermal,80mm, ReStick,Serial,A/C,PSIncluded,EDG

Sample break:

> C31C636363-Thermal,80mm, ReStick,
>
> Serial,A/C,PSIncluded,EDG

Comment: You can try `word-wrap:break-word;` May or may not work for you.

Comment: AFAIK breaking on spaces is hard-wired, where "spaces" includes things like zero-width spaces. Can you give an example of a string involving commas and how you would like it to break? Here's a [possibly relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574538/why-doesnt-break-word-work-on-a-long-string-with-commas).

Comment: @torazaburo added an example. There are no other zero-width spaces or anything added to it, just a simple string with commas.

Comment: There are no more recent solutions available for this issue.

Comment: I think the only way to go about it is using js to break it down the way you need it to. I don't think you need to worry about people not enabling js. I think 90% of the sites on the web would not work without js

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I am trying to break a word based on commas instead of spaces

You can't. CSS does not support that. Breaking on spaces is hard-wired.

You have no choice but to use JS to pre-process your content to perhaps insert zero-width spaces after commas, or perhaps do that on the server side.

Comment: Yeah I guess. I mean truthfully, I can probably accomplish this with a one liner regex to just add a space, thinking about it now. For db string limits the product descriptions we create don't have any spaces... just commas, so if there was a nice CSS solution for it that would've been awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest split the array on commas and then use the for loop.
below  code snippet is for vue.js

```
                 <div 
                 v-for="(arrayElement) in Array"
                 :key="`Array-${arrayElement.id}`"
                 class="column">
                    {{ arrayElement.name }}
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is simply use JS method 'replaceAll' in the view to add whitespace after each comma, then "break-word" works perfectly. Here is a sample of my code :

```
     <div className="break-word text-xl flex-5 text-left px-2">
      {props.data.zipCodes.replaceAll(',', ', ')} // <= Here
    </div>
```

In my case, a have a string composed of zipcodes, separated by only a comma. This is how it is store in the DB. (example : props.data.zipCodes = 13001,13002,13003,13004,13005,13006)

Answer (score 0):

Use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` HTML character, where you want to avoid braking.

```
C31C636363-Thermal,80mm,&nbsp;ReStick,Serial,A/C,PSIncluded,EDG
```